# How to get the Id of this response and then serialize it?

Tags: gmail, salesforce, apex

I need to get the id from a response with a for loop, then make a call and serialize the final result but I don't know how. This is the code:

```
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse response;
HttpRequest request;
String userEmail = 'myemail@mail.com';

request = new HttpRequest();
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setEndpoint('callout:Gmail_API/gmail/v1/users/myemail@mail.com/messages?q=from:anothermail@mail.com');


response = http.send(request); 

System.debug(response.getBody());
```

If I run an "Execute anonymous apex" I get this:

```
{
"messages": [
{
  "id": "17d9fdeb824b97be",
  "threadId": "17d9fdeb824b97be"
}
],
"resultSizeEstimate": 1
}
```

And essentially I need to return that response and get the Id and then make a call with the threadId and serialize it in a list which I have to use it in a Salesforce lightning component later. How do I do that? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code snippet to get the threadId value.

if(response.getStatusCode() == 200) {

```
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(response.getBody());
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {

            if (
                (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
                (parser.getText() == 'threadId')
            ) {

                parser.nextToken();
                threadId = parser.getText();
            }
        }
    }
```

**If it helps you, please mark it as the best answer to help others as well.**